# Is there an (easy) way to extract a substring from a HTTP Header Parameter?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm calling a rest api with pagination and in the response I get the "next" link in the HTTP Header, in the following format: Link `<https://aaaaaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/version/2.1.1/locations/?date_from=1601-01-01T00%3a00%3a00Z&date_to=2019-04-24T17%3a03%3a29Z&offset=100&limit=100`>; rel="next"

I can easily get the value of the HTTP Header link parameter

But there is no regex expression in Azure Logic Apps that I can use to further parse the link value in just the part between < and >

One option is to write an Azure Function that deals with this, but I'm looking for something simpler (if possible)

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "name": "newLink",
        "value": "@{outputs('HTTP')['headers']?['Link']}"
    }
}
```

the newLink variable now contains the complete value of link.
But I need only the part between the < and the >

Any hints on how I can parse the newLink variable into what I need (without using azure functions) is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `spilt()` function as shown below:

```
@split(split(triggerOutputs()['headers']?['Link'],'<')[1],'>')[0]
```

**Designer View**

[image: Designer]

**Code View**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@split(split(triggerOutputs()['headers']?['Link'],'<')[1],'>')[0]",
                    "statusCode": 200
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Postman Call:**

[image]

Comment: I had to wrap it in a test, but other then that all works.
"inputs": {
                            "name": "newLink",
                            "value": "@{if(equals(outputs('HTTP')['headers']?['Link'],null),'',split(split(outputs('HTTP')['headers']?['Link'],'<')[1],'>')[0])}"
                        }